# Gitbook force changing uppercase directories to lowercase in GitHub

Tags: git, uppercase, gitbook

When editing `.md` files in Gitbook after committing and merging through Gitbook changes are automatically pushed to my repo in GitHub. For some reason if I have a directory named `Controllers` and edit a markdown file under this directory in Gitbook. Once I edit and save my changes to the markdown file  under the `Controllers` directory through Gitbook the changes are successfully pushed to my repo in GitHub, but directory is renamed to `controllers` lower case.

Is there a way to prevent this and maintain the correct case of my directories?